# Using return in a generator function

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I have a homework for Python’s generators. This is what I’m asked:

> Write the `squares` function which: (**a**) accept an indefinite number of parameters (**assuming always integers**), and (**b**) be a generator function The squares should return in succession (according to the function of a generator) the square of the difference of each value from the average of all the values ​​given as input. In the main program call `squares` (in the correct way you want) to display the results returned when the input is given as the input parameters of the triples of 3, 4, 5. Also use the statistics library to calculate the average. Also add `return` to your code.

And this is my code:

```
import statistics as st

def squares(*args):
    mean_val = st.mean(args)
    
    for i in args:
        yield (i-mean_val)**2
    
    return
        
for k in squares(3,4,5):
    print(k)
```

But from what I have studied I need and `if` statement in the beginning of the function combined with `return` in order to stop the iteration.
Am I getting something wrong here?

Comment: "But from what I have studied I need and “if” statement in the beginning of the function combined with “return” in order to stop the iteration " no, you don't. `return` is only useful in generator functions when you want to stop the iteration early. A `return` at the end of the generator function definition statement like that is redundant, because it would cease the iteration there anyway, just like having a `return` there in a normal function would be redundant

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I need an if statement". You don't, as far as I can tell. I'm not really sure what you are asking, to be honest

Comment: The loop will stop when you've looped over all the args, so why would you need any condition here? BTW, you don't need to write `return` explicitely, this is the end of your function's execution anyway.

Comment: What make you think you've gotten something wrong? You don't need an `if` at the beginning and the unneeded `return` at the end is harmless.